# How can I use the bending stiffness of corrugated cardboard to determine maximum stacking heights of pallets loaded with glass bottles?

Tags: structural-analysis, beam

I am doing a project at the moment which involves improving the packaging operation at work. Right now I am looking at ways to improve packaging selection based on engineering principles, rather than guess work, which is what's being used currently.

We make many shapes and sizes of bottles and a major problem that we have is pallets which collapse because of poor packaging selection. The main problem is shown in the below image - the bottles in my (crude) sketch show a cross section of 1 stack of bottles.

[image: Bottle stack sketch.]

As you can see, the 'void' in the base of the bottle, which we call the 'push' is often large enough to allow the neck of the lower bottle to move a considerable distance in to it. This causes the corrugated board to be pinched between the 2 bottles and in effect is a 4-point beam loading situation, with the orientation of the forces flipped 180 degrees (relative to their orientation in the testing standard).

I'd like to know how I can relate the values from a 4-point bending stiffness test (BS ISO 5628:2012) and use these values to select an appropriate corrugated cardboard grade, based on the expected 4-point loading situation for each bottle.

From my limited knowledge of beams, I think I would need to:-

- Define a maximum load based on the expected mass of bottles above the
  point at which the maximum load is expected (i.e. on the neck of the
  lowest bottle in the stack.)
- define a maximum allowable deflection to
  work back and find a stiffness that would correspond to this
  deflection.
- input the lengths and positions of the forces based on
  the bottle geometry.

Some sticking points that I haven't been able to address:-

- Is my fundamental assumptions of this being a 4-point bending
  situation correct? We make round and square bottles which vastly complicate the loading situation. Obviously in my model I am only considering a cross section to relate this to a 4-point loading test.
- There are many bottles on each layer of a pallet. In my approach I
  have opted to simplify the model by only considering the mass
  directly above a single bottle. I am not sure, for example, how
  significant the contribution of the frictional forces from the
  surrounding bottles is.

**EDIT:** We do not used cardboard boxes. We used either pads or trays. In either case, the loading is always normal to the flat face of the cardboard. Edge compression never occurs with our packaging.

I'd really appreciate any feedback. Thanks.

Comment: most of the time boxes are supporting themselves with the walls. You can add some cardboard inserts to support the board above.

Comment: Does cardboard stiffness change with moisture content or will the packaging always be dry...

Comment: @ratchet freak. Edited for clarity

Comment: @Solar Mike. Once the pallet is assembled it is sealed within an air-tight shrink bag. The initial moisture content is difficult to determine unfortunately. Testing would need to be done close to use or all packaging would need to be kept in a climate-controlled area, both of which are significant issues.

Comment: You are loading discs, so will a 4 point solution be sufficient / accurate? And re my other comment will you be de-rating the stiffness to allow for moisture change? 5% or ...

Comment: can you manufacture a test rig to load a section of the cardboard between two bottles to have an idea of the load it can actually support - this could then be used to check the theoretical calculations...

Comment: This is one of the sticking points. Instinctively I would say that loading a disc would incur less deflection because of the additional material supporting the load compared to a more simple 4 point solutions - in which case giving a conservative result which I'd be happy with. I would look at de-rating the stiffness yes. I'm in contact with suppliers to see if they have data relating moisture content to stiffness. Regarding a test rig, this is likely quite doable - I could even incorporate clamps to apply a frictional force approximately equal to that causes by the surrounding bottles.

Comment: This type of board has different stiffness along and across the corrugations. In your picture the "4 point bending" may actually be buckling of the bottom surface of the board which is in compression. It might be better to use two thinner boards with the corrugations oriented at 90 degrees to each other between each layer of bottles, instead of one thick board.

Comment: @alephzero I've already looked at using materials which would effectively give cross-ply properties but we have restrictions on how bottles are packed which rules out using more than 1 board between each bottle layer. Structural composite boards are also far too expensive to use despite giving the required properties. Very good point about the stiffness in different fibre directions though, I hadn't considered this. There's an equation somewhere, however, which gives an over all material stiffness taking in to account the stiffness in the fibre direction and 90 degrees to it.

Comment: Also, regarding your point about the board being in compression on the underside - The required bending stiffness is the 1st of 2 parameters which must be met to be classed as a suitable material for a specific bottle - the other being the compressive strength of the board. I've got a calculation set to work out the minimum the CS needs to be to avoid be crushed by a particular bottle - so I think i've already accounted for any compression affects in this loading regime.

Comment: There are two different types of "compression" going on here. One is compression through the thickness of the sheet, caused by the weight of the bottle(s) above the sheet. The other is that when the sheet *bends*, the top surface will be in tension and the bottom surface will be in compression. The second one was what I was thinking might be causing buckling of the bottom surface.

Comment: Actually the different stiffness in two directions simplifies the problem, since you can start by ignoring what happens in the "stiff" direction and consider the behavior to be really like a 4-point beam bending test, which is easier to work with than concentric circles of pressure loading applied to a flat plate.